# WebPack loads all semantic-ui components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2, semantic-ui-react

I'm currently working on a project and i need to configure ***WebPack***. In the project, we are also using ***ReactJS*** and ***Semantic-UI***. Here is ***webpack.config.js*** :

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var BundleAnalyzer = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        react: ["react", "react-dom"],
        home: './assets/js/index.jsx',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["react"],
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "home",
            chunks: ['home'],
            filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzer(),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
                    { 
                      test: /\.jsx?$/,
                      exclude: /node_modules/,
                      loader: 'babel-loader',
                      options: { presets: ["es2015", "react"] }
                    },
                 ],
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
};
```

In ***assets/js/index.jsx*** file, we just have these import statements :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
```

By running webpack command, it outputs two files:

1. react.js: 779 KB
2. home-[some_hash_number].js: 1.5 MB

Using ***webpack-bundle-analyzer*** plugin, we get this:

[image: webpack-bundle-analyzer output]

As you see the red rectangle in the picture, all of the *semantic-ui* react components are bundled into *home.js* file although i just imported `Button` component from in *assets/js/index.js* file and that's why the output file gets too big.

Is there any way to just bundle needed components?

**UPDATE**

Reading ***@Alexander Fedyashov*** answer, i installed ***babel-plugin-lodash*** and updated *webpack.config.js* accordingly:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var BundleAnalyzer = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        react: ["react", "react-dom"],
        home: './assets/js/index.jsx',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "react",
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "home",
            chunks: ['home'],
            filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzer(),
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
                    { 
                      test: /\.jsx?$/,
                      exclude: /node_modules/,
                      loader: 'babel-loader',
                      options: {
                            plugins: ["lodash", { "id": ["lodash", "semantic-ui-react"] }],
                            presets: ["es2015", "react"],
                      }
                    },
                 ],
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
};
```

Now everything is working and only needed components are loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be splitted by Webpack, but in fact tree shaking doesn't work. You can use `babel-plugin-lodash` as described in SUIR [docs](http://react.semantic-ui.com/usage#bundlers).

You should keep in mind, that some of SUIR's components are dependent from each other, i.e.:

- `Button` requires `Icon`  and `Label`
- `Label` requires `Icon` and `Image`
- `Image` requires `Dimmer`
- `Dimmer` requires `Portal`.

However, plugin will allow to strip such components as `Rail`, `Reveal` and `Advertisement` if you don't use them.

Comment: I did what you said and updated the post but babel-plugin-lodash didn't remove unused components. Please check if i have done anything wrong. Thanks

Comment: You don't check example config in SUIR's repository, you should define imports for transform in plugin: `["lodash", { "id": ["lodash", "semantic-ui-react"] }]`

Answer (score 1):

There is a new feature on Webpack 2 to solve this issue, read this article 
https://medium.com/@adamrackis/vendor-and-code-splitting-in-webpack-2-6376358f1923

Comment: I already have done code splitting in my webpack config by separating App and ReactJS code. I read the link but i couldn't find the way to remove unnecessary bundled modules. Please provide more information.