# Extract duplicate javascript code using WebPack CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, commonschunkplugin

I'm using ***WebPack CommonsChunkPlugin*** to extract duplicate code and reduce JavaScript code size. I have two html pages and two entries for them. Also i've added ***ReactJs*** vendor entry. So far, in **webpack.config.js** we have:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        react: ["react", "react-dom"],
        home: './assets/js/home.jsx',
        about: './assets/js/about.jsx',
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'react',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),

        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.jsx?$/, 
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: { 
                  plugins: [["lodash", { "id": ["semantic-ui-react"] }]],
                  presets: ["es2015", "react"]
              }  
            },
        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
};
```

This configuration result with **webpack-bundle-analyzer**:

[image: webpack bundle analyzer output]

As you can see, there are some duplicate code, some in red area and some other in green area. I want to extract this js codes from home and about bundles into a separate bundle. To extract red area code, namely ***lodash*** library, i added these lines to webpack config:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'lodash',
    minChunks: function(module, count) {
        return module.context.indexOf('node_modules/lodash') >= 0;
    }
}),
```

But it's not working as expected and lodash library code is still in both home and about bundles, also webpack creates a bundle named lodash that is almost empty and contains no js library.

Any idea on how to fix it ? How about extracting green are codes?

Comment: Link: [Split “vendor” chunk using webpack 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784552/split-vendor-chunk-using-webpack-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by adding a common chunk to plugins. So final webpack config is :

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname,

    entry: {
        react: ["react", "react-dom"],
        home: './assets/js/home.jsx',
        about: './assets/js/about.jsx',
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },

    plugins: [

        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'react',
            filename: '[name].js',
            minChunks: Infinity,
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            chunks: ['home', 'about'],
            filename: '[name].js',
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { 
                    plugins: [
                      ["lodash", { "id": ["semantic-ui-react"] }]
                    ],
                    presets: ["es2015", "react"]
                }
            },
        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
};
```

And now bundle analyzer output is like this:

[image: analyzer output]

As it's shown in the picture, common semantic-ui-react and lodash libraries are now just in common bundle and not duplicated anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your are importing third party libs in each `.js/.jsx` file without importing it previously in a common file (normally called `vendor.js`). 
If you have this file that import all you dependencies and you include it as entry and to *CommonsChunkPlugin*, webpack won't include again your libs in your final bundles (`home.js` and `about.js`). The technique is called **code splitting** in webpack docs.

**vendor.js** (or a name that fit for your case)

```
import 'react';
import 'react-dom';
import 'lodash';
import 'semantic-ui-react';
//... all your npm packages
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        vendor: './assets/js/vendor.js,
        home: './assets/js/home.jsx',
        about: './assets/js/about.jsx',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
    ],

    //Rest of Your config ...
};
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <!-- AFTER YOUR HTML CODE -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bundles/vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bundles/home.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bundles/about.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

Check webpack code splitting docs:

- Old docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#split-app-and-vendor-code
- New Docs: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#explicit-vendor-chunk

Comment: I did whatever you said and ran webpack again. But the result is the same as before, lodash library is still in both files, just react and react-dom are bundled into vendor.js file. Here is bundle-analyzer output: [link](https://ibb.co/fmGk75)

Comment: Does it make a difference to use require('lodash') instead of import 'lodash' ? when using import 'lodash', there is no lodash code in vendor bundle but when i use require('lodash') instead, there is node_modules/lodash/lodash.js in vendor bundle. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I've note that the only difference between my webpack.config.js and yours is the `plugins: [["lodash", { "id": ["semantic-ui-react"] }]],` try to remove that from the babel-loader options. I think that could be that. If not, is weird.

Comment: `require('lodash')` and `import 'lodash'` has the same effect. `import` is ES6 syntax and try to use it if you can. I think if you have different results you could have some bad config in your babel. But use `require` if works for you.

Comment: You are right, the problem is babel plugin option. I removed it and used your config and it worked but removing plugin option creates a bigger problem. When babel lodash plugin is removed, unused imports are bundled into vendor. For example, all semantic-ui-react components are imported but most of them are unused. Before this question, i had the problem of bundling unused imports and asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386871/webpack-loads-all-semantic-ui-components). Solution is to use babel-lodash-plugin.

Comment: After all, i managed to solve the problem without removing babel-lodash plugin. I will post the config. Thanks for all your efforts :)